# Dimension of vector space and symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why the following statement is true?
I am so frustrated that I could not have any clue on this problem.

The dimension of the vector space of all symmetric 4 by 4 matrices is 10.

Please help me.

Comment: Try to write out a basis.  You should have two types of elements in your basis: those with only nonzero entries on the diagonal (4 of them), and those with nonzero entries in only the $ij$th entry and the $ji$th entry, for $i<j$ (6 of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

A symmetric $\,n\times n\,$ matrix is completely characterized by the elements on its main diagonal and by those above it. How many elements are there...?